# generated error terms for positioning based on a pre defined target accuracy level

Tags: gps, gnss, galileo, accuracy

I would like to ask a question about accuracy level and [precise point positioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precise_Point_Positioning) or PPP.

I'd like to design a system such that when the desired accuracy level is provided as an input, the corresponding error terms (ephemeris, clock and inter-frequency bias or IFB) are automatically determined based on an algorithm or mathematical approach.

It sounds a little tricky for me and I haven't found any studies or literature that has investigated something like this. Can somebody give me a hint how to approach to the problem, or maybe only some points to consider?

Thank you very much for the time and helps!

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* I've added in my best guess for what the acronyms PPP and IFB represent but I'm no expert; please feel free to edit further.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed tricky, mainly because you're trying to do the math problem in reverse.  That is, the most straightforward way to approach this is to start with a complicated model of how the big system fits together, approximate the sensitivity of the final result to the many different components of the error by taking partial derivatives, and then try to estimate how those components combine their contributions to the final position bias and covariance (root-sum-square is easy but not correct if there are correlations or nonlinearities among the contributing error terms).

There isn't just one answer to this problem:  many different designs with many different error sources may combine to achieve the same final position uncertainty.  You've posed what is often called an "inverse problem"; that is, you've asked roughly "what three numbers sum to 20", to which there are many different, equally correct, answers.  You need some other criteria of optimality, or source of constraints (like cost, time to develop, what kind of performance you can get out of off-the-shelf components) to be able to decide among the many different approaches.